# JS YouTube Embed swap inconsistent over different iOS versions

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, youtube-api

So I'm working on a mobile site that has some videos on it.  I am using the provided YouTube API for switching between flash and HTML5 on different devices, but I am using custom thumbnails for those for a couple different reasons.

I use some javascript to hide the YouTube iframe until a user clicks on a picture, and then it is supposed to swap out the image for the video onClick, calling the `switchItUp` method.

```
        var video = document.getElementById("VideoID");
        var image = document.getElementById("PlaceholderImage");
        video.style.display = "none";

        function switchItUp() {
            var video = document.getElementById("VideoID");
            var image = document.getElementById("PlaceholderImage");
            image.style.display = "none";
            video.style.display = "block";
        }
```

The YouTube code, as specified by the API, is as follows (and works when on the page alone):

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/BaKcl0Qg13o?autoplay=1" width="300" height="190"></iframe>
```

Here's the fun part.

- This works great in Safari on 4.0.
- In 4.1 the onClick shows the video, but you can't play it.
- In 4.2 the video doesn't show at all, but leaves a giant blank space on the page when the image hides.

It works great on all the desktop browsers, so debugging this is a problem.

Any help is appreciated! TYIA!

---

**EDIT:** The player must be on autoplay for the swap to work on 1 click, so it must start out as display:none on the page.

Also, would the container cause this problem?  It's currently rendering inside a `<span>` on the page, that doesn't have display:block set before display:none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the autoplay doesn't work in 4.2 we decided to get rid of the thumbnail swap.  There isn't a way to do this that works across all iOS versions.  So we are just using some youtube-generated thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide the video by positioning it off the screen rather than using `display=none`. This is a classic work around for this kind of problem.

```
video.style.position = 'absolute';
video.style.top = '-10000px';
video.style.left = '-10000px';
```

Then you can 'show' it with

```
video.style.position = 'static'
```

Comment: Sadly, that won't work because the player has to be on autoplay in order for the user to not have to click twice, so it cannot be positioned off the page.  I'm avoiding loading the player on page load to save bandwidth and a user's data plan if on 3G. Thanks for the suggestion though.